# Where do I find Internet Explorer downloads?

Tags: internet-explorer, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find edited Word attachment opened via Windows Mail (Vista)](https://superuser.com/questions/41990/find-edited-word-attachment-opened-via-windows-mail-vista)

I opened a Word document from my email without clicking "Save As." I typed up 10 pages, and then hit close, and then Save.

However, I cannot find a trace of that file on my Windows 7 machine. Where is it? I've looked in Download and temp. I understand that I made a mistake, and any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a search on your My Computer , search for `*.doc` or `*.docx`, depending on the file format you saved at, then arrange the search results using Last Modified in descending order. Your document should be near the top of the search results if it hasn't disappeared yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the file, then clicking save as, should show you the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Start Word, and look in the "Recent Documents".
If you find it there, you can open it, and do "Save as..." to see where it is located, as "Save as..." defaults location to the open document.